# Javascript input field should append in div whille Typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I am building an Url-Generator for google analytics. Currently, the Url is appending if I press the submit button. But I want the URL to append while typing in the input. How can I do that with Javascript to get rid of the submit button?

PS: I also want that if I make changes for example in the third input field that the sequence isn't changing (that the content of the third input field isn't appending at last, after I have changed the input value).

HERE'S MY CURRENT CODE THAT LET'S THE URL APPEND AFTER PRESSING THE SUBMIT BUTTON:

```
//create URL
submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
    outputField.value = "";
    output = "";
    //lowercases all field inputs
    if(input01.value !== "" && input02.value !== "") {
        output += input01.value + "?utm_source=" + input02.value;
        if(createClicked === false) {
            $("#outputWrapper").slideToggle(550);
            createClicked = true;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Website Url and Campaign Source can't be empty");
    }
    if(input03.value !== "") {
        output += "&utm_medium=" + input03.value;
    }
    if(input04.value !== "") {
        output += "&utm_campaign=" + input04.value;
    }
    if(input05.value !== "") {
        output += "&utm_term=" + input05.value;
    }
    if(input06.value !== "") {
        output += "&utm_content=" + input06.value;
    }
    //output.toLowerCase();
    //removes space through %20 in output
    output = output.replace(/\s/g,'%20');

    outputField.textContent = output;
})
```

Comment: You can attach an `input` event handler to the text fields to generate the url.  `input` happens any time the value of an input changes, in contrast to `change` which happens once the element has lost focus

Comment: add an `onkeypress` or `oninput` listener to your `input`, that way, every char typed will call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attach an eventListener to your `input` and listen for the `input` event

```js
let myText = document.querySelector('#myText');
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('input', function(){
  myText.innerText = this.value;
});
```

```css
span{
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" />

<span id="myText"></span>
```